# React. How to update the state of a clicked element

Tags: reactjs

I have some elements inside an array that shares a same state. I need to update only the clicked one in order to add one more item to my shopping cart. How can i do this without changing the others?

My initial state looks like this:

```
class ShoppingCart extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      isEmpty: true,
      cartItems: [],
      count: 0,
    };
    this.getStoredProducts = this.getStoredProducts.bind(this);
    this.handleButtonIncrease = this.handleButtonIncrease.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.getStoredProducts();
  }

  handleButtonIncrease() {
    this.setState((prevState) => ({
      count: prevState.count + 1,
    }));
  }

  getStoredProducts() {
    const getFromStorage = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('cartItem'));
    if (getFromStorage !== null) {
      this.setState({
        cartItems: getFromStorage,
      }, () => {
        const { cartItems } = this.state;
        if (cartItems.length) {
          this.setState({ isEmpty: false });
        }
      });
    }
  }

  render() {
    const { isEmpty, cartItems, count } = this.state;
    const emptyMsg = (
      <p data-testid="shopping-cart-empty-message">Seu carrinho está vazio</p>
    );
    return (
      <div>
        { isEmpty ? (emptyMsg) : (cartItems.map((item) => (
          <ShoppingCartProduct
            key={ item.id }
            id={ item.id }
            count={ count }
            cartItems={ item }
            handleButtonIncrease={ this.handleButtonIncrease }
          />
        )))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like this should be `ShoppingCartProduct`'s responsibility. If you remove this `count` and `setCount` logic from your `ShoppingCart` component and create it inside of the `ShoppingCartProducts` component, each one of the items will have their own `count` state that can be updated independently.

One other way of seeing this is directly mutating each `cartItem`, but since you didn't specify their format there's no way of knowing if they're storing any information about quantity so I would go with the first approach.

Answer (score 1):

`handleButtonIncrease` can accept `item.id` as parameter so that it can update the `state.cartItems`.

```
  handleButtonIncrease(itemId) {

    const cartItems = this.state.cartItems.map(item => {
      return item.id === itemId 
        ? { 
          // apply changes here for the item with itemId
        }
        : item
    });

    this.setState((prevState) => ({
      cartItems,
      count: prevState.count + 1,
    }));
  }
```

After that, update your callback as well:

```
handleButtonIncrease={ () => this.handleButtonIncrease(item.id) }
```